# Upgradable contract proxy pattern: Get the invoked method name in the fallback function

Tags: delegatecall, fallback-function, proxy-contracts

I have a proxy smart contract and I would like to get the name of the called method in the fallback function. Is there a way?

For example, if I call the function **getName()** (stored in the logic contract), then in the fallback function (of the proxy contract) I would like to get the invoked function name, in this case **getName**.

```solidity
contract Proxy {
  function () payable external {
    /* I would like to get here the name of the invoked function */
    _fallback();
  }

  function _fallback() internal {
    _willFallback();
    _delegate(_implementation());
  }


  function _implementation() internal view returns (address);

  function _delegate(address implementation) internal { ... }

  function _willFallback() internal { }
}
```

[Please, check here the full code of the proxy smart contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/blob/master/packages/lib/contracts/upgradeability/Proxy.sol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full name of the function being called is not passed to the smart contract, but only the first 4 bytes of the hash of function signature.  These 4 bytes you can obtain as `msg.sig`.  See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/units-and-global-variables.html) for details.